# Как сделать вывод пар без дубликатов?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Я вывел

```
SELECT a1.name, b2.name
FROM Klass AS a1, Klass AS b2
WHERE a1.birthday = b2.birthday AND a1.id <> b2.id
```

Но при этом получются дубликаты, так как (A B) те же самые данные, что и (B A). Как сделать вывод без дубликатов?

*SQLite Version 3.11.2*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно заменить условие `a1.id <> b2.id` на `a1.id < b2.id`, тогда имена будут выводиться всегда по возрастанию `id`, без обратной перестановки.